# Loops miss handling?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a div named as container and inside container I have two div column1 and column2.Inside column1 and column2 I have to fetch record from database and have to show it here.My code look like this

```
  <div id="container" style="height:600px; width:600px; border:1px solid #990000">
 <?php $str=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());
  while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($str){
 ?>
<div id="column1" style="height:200px; width:295px; border:1px solid #0000FF;float:left;">

  /*Here this record should be of id=1 */
 <img src="<?php echo $rec['pic'];?>" alt="No image" />
 <?php echo $rec['detail'];
</div>
<div id="column2" style="height:200px; width:295px; border:1px solid #0000FF;float:left;">

 /*Here this record should be of id=2 */
<img src="<?php echo $rec['pic'];?>" alt="No image" />
 <?php echo $rec['detail'];
</div>
 <?php } ?>
```

I want to have in column1 record of user having id=1 and in column2 id=2 and again in column1 id=3 and column2 id=4 and so on. Any help me in this looping?

Comment: what is this question has to do with `css`?

Comment: **DON'T** use those ID's for the columns. Each ID is meant to exist only once in a document. Choose classes instead when you need to use multiple instances of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a deprecated extension, by the way. I highly recommend you use the newer [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) extensions to interface with your MySQL database in PHP for new development as this will make your job so much easier.

The answer to what you want to do is simply to traverse over the result set in multiples of two, which can be achieved as demonstrated below with the PDO extension.

```
<div id="container">
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'mysqlusername', 'mysqlpassword');
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM users');
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/* And now do your loop in pairs of two */

foreach (array_chunk($result, 2) as $pair) {
    ?>
    <div id="1">
        <?php echo $pair[0]['detail']; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <?php echo $pair[1]['detail']; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
</div>
```

The other option is to use a counter and flip it with each iteration then follow that by a condition to determine which div you want to output for this iteration of the loop.

```
<div id="container">
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'mysqlusername', 'mysqlpassword');
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM users');
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/* And now do your loop in pairs of two */

$div = 0;
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $div ^= 1; // bitwise XOR
    if ($div) { // If it's odd show the first div
        ?>
        <div id="1">
            <?php echo $row['detail']; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else {  // If it's even show the second div
        ?>
        <div id="2">
            <?php echo $row['detail']; ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: An extra +1 (if I could add) for the bitwise XOR part. Only thing is, I would update the ID's since multiple elements with the same ID should not exist in a DOMDocument.

Comment: Well, I could have added a modulus option as well, but I didn't want to overwhelm the OP :)

Comment: Bitwise is still the most clever approach, I think. I was just writing one with the modulus myself but I didn't post it because I figured out you guys have already answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what loops are all about. Should look something like this:

```
<div id="container" style="height:600px; width:600px; border:1px solid #990000">
<?php
$count = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $count++;
?>
    <div id="column<?php if($count&1) { echo "1"; } else { echo "2"; } ?>" style="height:200px; width:295px; border:1px solid #0000FF;float:left;">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['pic']; ?>" alt="No image" />
        <?php echo $row['detail']; ?>
    </div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain this <?php if($count&1).. part?

Comment: It checks if count is an even or odd number. :)